# Get previous sibling of div element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the previous id and I'm doing the following but I get "undefined" from alert(id); So in this example it should return **step_1** when they click the left key. Thanks for your help.

JavaScript:

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
      id = $('.steps.onit').prev().attr('id');
      alert(id);
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
  }
});
```

UPDATE 
HTML (div are background image):

```
<div id="container-steps">
    <a href="some url"><div id="step_1" class="steps"></div></a>
    <a href="some url"><div id="step_2" class="steps onit">selected one</div></a>
    <a href="some url"><div id="step_3" class="steps"></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: There must be something else going on here, this DOES work - see http://jsfiddle.net/ND5TP/ Is it possible you have multiple elements with the class "steps onit" ?

Comment: Working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MEgYy/) as well...

Comment: it IS returning `step_1`. both on chrome n firefox. Which browser you are using?

Comment: I know why please see my update...I didn't reproduce properly the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev) finds a sibling (on the same level, sharing a parent) not cousins.

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
      id = $('.steps.onit').parent().prev().children('.steps').attr('id');
      alert(id);
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
  var obj = $('.steps.onit');
  var id = obj.attr("id");
  alert(id);}else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right}});
```